# YouTube Data Api Quota exceeded even if actually not

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Daily quota usage is app 50% under limit but still getting error "code: 400 - message: The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload".
[usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuhRr.png)
[limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5xz7.png)

Anyone had similar problem?

Cheers,
DN

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'd recommend to address this issue directly to Google through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Will do that, thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two separate quotas that youtube enforces.

From an application standpoint, every youtube api call consumes quota of which the cost is listed on the [youtube support page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

Additionally, there is a separate floating quota (depending on a variety of factors) of the number of videos you are allowed to upload per day to a specific channel, this is rather poorly documented but depends on both the amount of verification you've provided Google as well as the traction (subscribers/views) that your channel has.

At the lower tiers, this will be around 10-15 videos and at the higher tiers may top out around 150.